An error occurs in the Android studio project in setting.gradle,kts
enter image description here
I can't figure out how to fix it. Due to this error, the assembly cannot be performed because the program does not see the modules. Previously, there was something that came out Sync now when changing the parameters, now this is not there either. Can you tell me how to fix the problem?
version android studio 2021.1.1
errors on photo
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/GZBETuQE.png

Did you see this?

This is a warning, not an error; it shouldn't affect the build compilation unless you have allWarningsAsErrors set to true - in this case, it's just that repositoriesMode is currently an API where its behaviour/configuration could be changed at any point
